# Fetch result in Jquery Lightbox using PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to fetch information (`u_name` and `u_email`) from database using AJAX into a JQuery lightbox. I'm having problems with the Ajax part.
My `HTML` structure is:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <a href="#" id="showe3" class="button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
    <a href="#" id="showe4" class="button lfloat">Show it</a>
</div>
```

So, the user clicks on one of the `id`, which is matched in the database table, and the result is fetched.

The Javacript code is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id').ecko({  //ecko is a JQuery lightbox function which im using
        height: 200,
        holderClass: 'custom',
        template: '<p>About</p>' +
        '<div>' +
        '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="b1">u_name</a>' +
        '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="b2">u_email</a>' +
        '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="b2">More</a>' +
        '</div>'
    });
});
```

The `Ajax` will be:

```
 $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'functions/db.php',                        
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',     
    success: function(data){
        var name = data[0];
        var email = data[1];

        //What should be here??

    } });
```

`PHP` code will be like:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE `id` = " what should be written here? "); 
    $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);   

    echo json_encode($array);
```

I've posted everything I tried. I don't know a way of connecting the `id` clicked to pass it to `php`'s line of `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE`id`= "")` and then connecting Ajax and the Jquery lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

When someone clicks the button, pass the ID to the data option in ajax, and fetch it on the serverside:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',                              
        url: 'functions/db.php',                        
        data: {id: this.id},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#id').ecko({
            height: 200,
            holderClass: 'custom',
            template: '<p>About</p>' +
                '<div>' +
                '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="b1">'+data[0]+'</a>' +
                '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="b2">'+data[1]+'</a>' +
                '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="b2">More</a>' +
                '</div>'
        });
    });

});
```

Then use the data in the markup, but you can only do that once the ajax call is completed.

PHP

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE `id` = " $id);
```

consider moving onto PDO, as mysql is deprecated!

Comment: There shouldn't be a `;` after `</div>`.

Comment: It's more of a "how you should do it", not "exactly like this will work", as it's a very general question with just "what to type here" stuff. The SQL query above probably does'nt work, as you'll need to insert the variable properly, and you should probably test the ajax call by just echoing a simple string to see that it works before you try more advanced stuff, and use some console.logs to check that the click() function works etc. What is commonly known as basic fault finding.

Comment: Right. I figured out the necessary statements.
Also 1 more thing I wanted to inquire: **I have to click twice on the button for the first time to fetch the results**. Is that normal?